# Como fazer update em lote com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo um arquivo `.csv` com duas colunas, uma com o `id` e outra com o `status` do meu produto, preciso alterar esses produtos para o `status` 0 (zero), ou seja, inativar os mesmos, mas a quantidade de produtos ultrapassa 400 registros, como posso ler esse arquivo e efetuar um update em lote?
Não consegui montar nada que funcionasse.

Fiz um código seguindo uma dica, ficou assim:

```
        // ARQUIVO NO SERVIDOR
    $arquivo = 'c:\inativos.txt';

    // ARRAY QUE RECEBERÁ DADOS IMPORTADOS
    $arquivoArr = array();

    // SOMENTE LEITURA
    $arq = fopen($arquivo, 'r');

    $i = 0;
    while(!feof($arq)){

            $conteudo = fgets($arq);
            $arquivoArr[$i] = $conteudo;                
            $i++;
    }


  // CONEXÃO COM BD
  require_once('Connections/conexao.php');     

  foreach($arquivoArr as $linha):

        mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
        $sqlUp = "UPDATE produtos SET status = 0 WHERE id_produto = $linha";    
        $fim = mysql_query($sqlUp,$conexao) or die ( "Erro alterando dados no Banco de Dados" );

  endforeach;
```

Mas dando um `echo` na variável `$sqlUp` me retorna isso: `UPDATE produtos SET status = 0 WHERE id_produto = ��1`

Comment: não entendi, esse seu código já resolve o problema? quando vc diz "minha contribuição" é o status que vc está até agora?

Comment: Não fui eu quem colocou esse código, mas uma edição do @Marcelo Gomes, também não entendi.

Comment: Agora foi o fim mesmo... em vez de responder, ele edita o poste e coloca um código...

Comment: Para não deletar a contribuição do @Marcelo Gomes, http://pastebin.com/wR2stu2a coloquei no PasteBin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o `REPLACE INTO`.

O `REPLACE INTO` funciona como `INSERT` ou `UPDATE` numa única instrução.

Exemplo

```
REPLACE INTO tabela
(coluna_id, coluna_status)
VALUES
(1,0),
(2,0),
(3,0)
```

Numa única query é atualizado múltiplos registros.

Apenas esteja ciente de que caso um determinado *id* não exista, ao invés de atualizar, será adicionado como novo.

Obviamente, precisa ler o arquivo .csv e preparar a query. Como isso não é o foco da questão, acho irrelevante explicar essa parte.